# How to count entries in Realm Database with a specific value

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a Realm object with property dateCreated:

```
class Category: Object {
  @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
  @objc dynamic var itemn : String = ""
  @objc dynamic var dateCreated : String = ""

  var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Datee.self , property: "cetegories")

  }
```

I want to be able to query all categories by var dateCreated in order to count them and create appropriate number or rows in my tableView.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

}
```

Comment: When you say you say you want to query all categories by dateCreated, do you mean you want to query all categories with a non empty string variable dateCreated?

Answer (score 1):

When you say query all categories by dateCreated, I'm assuming you mean all categories with a non empty dateCreated string . You would do this as follows:

```
var datedCategoriesCount = realm.objects(Category.self).filter("dateCreated != ''").count
```

Comment: I believe you forgot to append `.count` to the result of `filter`

Comment: @rs7 Performance wise, there is no better way to fetch the count without actually getting the objects themselves? Thanks